# I try to reapply to GitHub Education. and it's through this error

Tags: github

I try to reapply to GitHub Education. and it's through this error. How to solve this error?

Your application cannot be reviewed until you fix the following:
Modify your browser settings to allow GitHub to use your location information. Once location is allowed you MUST cancel your current application and begin again.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: i am using google chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings > Privacy and Security > Site Settings > Location> set "Default Behavior" to "Sites can ask for your location" and if Github is in "Not allowed to see your location" remove it from that list and change it to "Allowed to see your location". Hope this helps.

Comment: This problem is still not solved by this.

Comment: But I got a new solution. if anyone faces this problem, please cancel the whole procedure and then can try again from Mobile.  Thanks

Comment: @FarzanaPomy I tried it on iOS and it worked. My settings -> Disable iCloud Private Relay, Use Firebox browser, Enable location access.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with you. I tried on Chrome for so many times, but it just did not work. Finally, I choose to have a try on FireFox, just after I clicked the submit button and I successfully became the GitHub Pro User!!!

Answer (score 0):

If u still do it after allow github for location in your browser, try another browser, if still cant, try the other again. Dont give, we can do it!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. My os was by default blocking all geolocalisation request.

Going to the os parameters and changing that solved it.

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use your Mobile with this link: https://education.github.com/pack

It will allow applying GitHub Education.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

Use browser in private profile. It has worked to me